# Sublime Text 3's plugin_host just crashed, and now the interface is messed up. How do I restore it?

Tags: plugins, sublime-text-3

I just got an alert from Sublime Text 3 with the following message:

> plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted

I don't have many plugins: Package Control, CoffeeScript, AngularJS, and LESS. I have a custom theme ([Seti UI](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Seti_UI)) but now the theme's disappeared, and in fact the entire interface has become messed up. The status bars are missing, and the tabs are behaving *really* strangely:

[image: status bar is invisible, and text in tabs is being written over itself]

What can I do to get it working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General reports on the 'net indicate that plugin_host can crash for various reasons, like a recently-updated plugin with a major error in it. In those cases, the general advice seems to be to disable suspect addons one by one to identify the culprit.

For users with a custom theme and Package Control, though, the culprit is often simple: there's a package control bug that can sometimes just spontaneously disable plugins. When that one of those plugins is *your theme,* the interface will break and the plugin_host will report that it has crashed.

For now, Sublime Text is operating well enough though. Go to **Preferences** then **Settings — User**, find the **"ignored_packages"** entry, and see if your theme is in there:

[image: "Seti_UI" is the last entry in the "ignored_packages" list in my settings]

In this case, since Seti UI is in there, we'll select it and delete it. Don't forget to *also* delete the comma on the line beforehand: the last line in the "ignored_packages" list *must not* end with a comma, but the rest of the lines should.

[image: selecting the "Seti_UI" entry, plus the comma on the line before]

After deleting that line, save your file, and suddenly Sublime Text should be looking normal again:

[image: Hooray! It looks ordinary again.]

<sub>(This answer was based on a solution from [qgates on the sublime text forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=53459#p53459) that worked for me, and I'm reproducing the solution here for posterity + ease of finding it.)</sub>